# Colored Histogram HSV 1D

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm tryed to create a histogram 1d from image like this

[image]

But i have no idea how to do this. Can anybody help me?

This is my simples code for HSV histogram:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('sample/sample4.jpg')

cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

H, S, V = image[:,:,0],image[:,:,1],image[:,:,2]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.subplot(311)                             #plot in the first cell
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.5)
plt.title("Hue")
plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(H), bins=180)
plt.subplot(312)                             #plot in the second cell
plt.title("Saturation")
plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(S), bins=128)
plt.subplot(313)                             #plot in the third cell
plt.title("Luminosity Value")
plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(V), bins=128)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for help me

Comment: To achieve the above figure, you need to *cluster* the hue channel into 16 bins to determine the dominant colour for each bin, then calculate the frequency of appearance for each dominant colour.  Calculating the histogram of the entire image is inadequate to achieve your desired figure as you will be plotting the frequency of appearance for every possible hue value.  The figure shown is plotting what is predominantly visible in the image.  Even so, you also have to take the saturation and value into account so without further context, this question can't be answered unambiguously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that using Python/OpenCV/Scipy/Matplotpy, but in BGR colors.

- Read the input
- Use kmeans to reduce colors to 16 colors
- Get arrays of unique colors and counts of unique colors
- Plot each count as bar colorized by the color
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster

# read image into range 0 to 1
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg') / 255

# set number of colors
number = 16

# quantize to 16 colors using kmeans
h, w, c = img.shape
img2 = img.reshape(h*w, c)
kmeans_cluster = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=number)
kmeans_cluster.fit(img2)
cluster_centers = kmeans_cluster.cluster_centers_
cluster_labels = kmeans_cluster.labels_

# need to scale back to range 0-255 and reshape
img3 = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w, c)*255.0
img3 = img3.astype('uint8')

cv2.imshow('reduced colors',img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# reshape img to 1 column of 3 colors
# -1 means figure out how big it needs to be for that dimension
img4 = img3.reshape(-1,3)

# get the unique colors
colors, counts = np.unique(img4, return_counts=True, axis=0)
print(colors)
print("xxx")
print(counts)
unique = zip(colors,counts)

# function to convert from r,g,b to hex 
def encode_hex(color):
    b=color[0]
    g=color[1]
    r=color[2]
    hex = '#'+str(bytearray([r,g,b]).hex())
    print(hex)
    return hex

# plot each color
fig = plt.figure()
for i, uni in enumerate(unique):
    color = uni[0]
    count = uni[1]
    plt.bar(i, count, color=encode_hex(color))

# show and save plot
plt.show()
fig.savefig('barn_color_historgram.png')
plt.close(fig)
```

Resulting Colored Histogram Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate version in Python/OpenCV that is sorted by HSV Value.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cluster

# read image into range 0 to 1
img = cv2.imread('barn.jpg') / 255

# set number of colors
number = 16

# quantize to 16 colors using kmeans
h, w, c = img.shape
img2 = img.reshape(h*w, c)
kmeans_cluster = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=number)
kmeans_cluster.fit(img2)
cluster_centers = kmeans_cluster.cluster_centers_
cluster_labels = kmeans_cluster.labels_

# need to scale back to range 0-255 and reshape
img3 = cluster_centers[cluster_labels].reshape(h, w, c)*255.0
img3 = img3.astype('uint8')

cv2.imshow('reduced colors',img3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# reshape img to 1 column of 3 colors
# -1 means figure out how big it needs to be for that dimension
img4 = img3.reshape(-1,3)

# get the unique colors
colors, counts = np.unique(img4, return_counts=True, axis=0)

# compute HSV Value equals max(r,g,b)
values = []
for color in colors:
    b=color[0]
    g=color[1]
    r=color[2]
    v=max(b,g,r)
    values.append(v)

# zip colors, counts, values together
unique = zip(colors,counts,values)

# make list of color, count, value
ccv_list = []
for color, count, value in unique:
    ccv_list.append((color, count, value))
    
# function to define key as third element
def takeThird(elem):
    return elem[2]

# sort ccv_list by Value (brightness)
ccv_list.sort(key=takeThird)

# plot each color sorted by increasing Value (brightness)
# pyplot uses normalized r,g,b in range 0 to 1
fig = plt.figure()
length = len(ccv_list)
for i in range(length):
    item = ccv_list[i]
    color = item[0]
    b = color[0]/255
    g = color[1]/255
    r = color[2]/255
    count = item[1]
    plt.bar(i, count, color=((r,g,b)))

# show and save plot
plt.show()
fig.savefig('barn_color_histogram2.png')
plt.close(fig)
```

Result:

[image]